# Excel Address County Appending

Tags: database, excel, formula

I have a sheet of addresses which do not have the counties in the "add4" column.
I also have a separate sheet of town names and the corresponding counties.

I would like to append the county names to the "add4" column table where they match the town names using a formula.

Here's the tables...

Address Sheet (sheet1):

```
  A            B              C            D          E
 1 Name         Add1           Add2         Add3       Add4
 2 John Smith   1 High Street  Little Town  Chelmsford
 3 Keith Jones  44 Tall House  Bransby      Lincoln
```

Town & County Sheet (sheet2):

```
  A              B
1 Town           County
2 Chelmsford     Essex
3 Lincoln        Lincolnshire
```

In the example above the formula should return the following:

```
 A            B              C            D          E
 1 Name         Add1           Add2         Add3       Add4
 2 John Smith   1 High Street  Little Town  Chelmsford Essex
 3 Keith Jones  44 Tall House  Bransby      Lincoln    Lincolnshire
```

Please can you advise on the formula I should be using.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This video](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) may be interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use the vlookup() function

In cell E2 of your address sheet put below formula (change the TownCountySheet with actual sheet name where you have town & county )

```
=vlookup(D2,'TownCountySheet'!A:B,2,false)
```